# create divs at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dom

I'm creating a simulation. This involves adding a series of events. I am wanting to click a button which creates a new event that will hold the settings for this event. Ultimately I need to be able to create divs on the fly.

To get a better understanding of want i'm wanting please refer to the following link:

https://moqups.com/batemsj1/78KI5Nlg/

Whats the best way to do this. I plan to use ASP.NET web forms. From my understanding I somehow have to add a div to the DOM. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new element and append it to the desired parent.

So say you have a parent element with ID "parent" and want to add a div to it:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var textContentForDiv = document.createTextNode("This is the text that goes inside the new div");
newDiv.appendChild(textContentForDiv);

document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(newDiv);
```